# how to bundle back up a git bundle file

Tags: git, terminal

I received a git bundle file or(file.bundle) as an email attachment. I opened it up by:

```
  git init
  git pull file.bundle master
```

The email said in order to bundle it back put in git bundle but in the terminal I get this:

```
usage: git bundle create <file> <git-rev-list args>
 or: git bundle verify <file>
 or: git bundle list-heads <file> [<refname>...]
 or: git bundle unbundle <file> [<refname>...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `git bundle create file.bundle --branches master`